# Empty array when I try to spread two array together

Tags: javascript

Hi pushing content using a for loop to two variables and trying to merger the two arrays. Do I need an async function?

```js
let x = []
let y = []

function coords(points) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= points; i++) {
    const result = i
    x.push(result)
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <= points; i++) {
    const result = i
    y.push(i * 0.25)
  }
}
coords(10)

const xy = [...x, ...y] //<- results in an empty array?
console.log(xy)
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: Looks like it works fine. This is what I get with your code after logging xy to the console - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5]

Comment: Oh I wonder if it is was a codepen issue? Thanks for looking at it though.